# ThirdPersonController Unity not moving coherently with moving platforms

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple platformer, using the third person controller developed by Unity with the StarterAssets. I have created a simple script that moves a platform through a path of waypoints. The `MovingPlatform` script is the following:

```
using StarterAssets;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
        {
                [Header("Movement")]
                [SerializeField] private WaypointPath waypointPath;
                [SerializeField] private float speed = 1f;

                private Transform _platformTransform;

                private int _targetWaypointIndex;

                private Transform _previousWaypoint;
                private Transform _targetWaypoint;

                private float _timeToWaypoint;
                private float _elapsedTime;

                private void Start()
                {
                        // Get the transform of the platform
                        _platformTransform = transform.parent;
                        
                        TargetNextWaypoint();
                }

                private void Update()
                {
                        MoveToWaypoint();
                }

                private void TargetNextWaypoint()
                {
                        // Get the current waypoint
                        _previousWaypoint = waypointPath.GetWaypoint(_targetWaypointIndex);
                        
                        // Increase the index and get the next waypoint
                        _targetWaypointIndex = waypointPath.GetNextWaypointIndex(_targetWaypointIndex);
                        _targetWaypoint = waypointPath.GetWaypoint(_targetWaypointIndex);

                        _elapsedTime = 0f;
                        
                        // Compute the time needed to go from the previous to the next waypoint based on their distance
                        var distanceToWaypoint = Vector3.Distance(_previousWaypoint.position, _targetWaypoint.position);
                        _timeToWaypoint = distanceToWaypoint / speed;
                }

                private void MoveToWaypoint()
                {
                        // Update the elapsed time
                        _elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

                        // Update the position of the platform based on the percentage of the moving time
                        var elapsedPercentage = _elapsedTime / _timeToWaypoint;
                        _platformTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_previousWaypoint.position, _targetWaypoint.position, elapsedPercentage);
                        
                        if (elapsedPercentage >= 1f)
                        {
                                // Move to the next waypoint
                                TargetNextWaypoint();
                        }
                }
                
                private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
                {
                        Debug.Log($"Player entered trigger: {other.name}");
                        
                        if (other.GetComponent<ThirdPersonController>())
                        {
                                // TODO: NOT WORKING WITH ANIMATIONS
                                // Set the player's parent to this object's transform
                                other.GetComponentInParent<Player>().gameObject.transform.parent = _platformTransform;
                        }
                }

                private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
                {
                        Debug.Log($"Player exited trigger: {other.name}");
                        
                        if (other.GetComponent<ThirdPersonController>())
                        {
                                // Remove this object's transform as the player's parent
                                other.GetComponentInParent<Player>().gameObject.transform.parent = null;
                        }
                }
        }
```

The script for the `WaypointPath` is the following:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointPath : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform GetWaypoint(int index)
        {
            return transform.GetChild(index);
        }

        public int GetNextWaypointIndex(int currentWaypointIndex)
        {
            var nextIndex = currentWaypointIndex + 1;

            if (nextIndex == transform.childCount)
            {
                nextIndex = 0;
            }
            
            return nextIndex;
        }
    }
```

The hierarchy is the following:

[image: Hierarchy]

In the scene we have:

> the platform that has a platform trigger child object, that I (would like to) use to set the PlayerController as a child of the platform

> two waypoints to have an horizontal movement of the platform

> the PlayerController provided by Unity

I would like to have the PlayerController moving in a coherent way with the platform, and for this reason I am putting it as a child of the platform itself. However, it does not work. It does only very little movements, without moving as the platform does. Can someone help me with that?